# Is there a way to tell an if statement if a condition is true do nothing

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, random

Creating a dice roll game in c# WPF using a random number generator for each dice. If a dice is clicked I want to protect that value so that when the user rolls the dice it does not change.
I have implemented a button click for each dice button that on click disables the button.

```
 private void Dicebtn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dicebtn3.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

That works perfectly. The part I am not sure of is how to tell my dicerollBtn to not generate a number if the button was clicked.
Roll code is here

```
private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Dicebtn1_Click) rndNum1 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
        else 
        rndNum2 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
        rndNum3 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
        rndNum4 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
        rndNum5 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
        rndNum6 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
```

Comment: check IsEnabled? `if (Dicebtn1.IsEnabled)`

Comment: Are you trying to just call `rndNum2 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);` in the `else` portion and the rest of the lines every time? It's not clear what you're intending there because of the lack of proper indentation/braces.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarification. What I want is to generate the RndNum only if the button was not clicked. For example if the button for RndNum2 was clicked I want to ignore generating the number. Does that clarify?

Comment: Also note that the max value argument to `Next` is **exclusive**, so you're only picking numbers between `1` and `5` in your code.

Comment: Your `else` only assigns `rndNum2`. The num 3 through 6 are always assigned. Do you mean you want blocks, surrounded by curly braces `{}`? Like `if (...) { ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think he doesn't want an `else` block at all. Just 6 `if`s.

Comment: In answer to the question in your title, "yes", just follow it with empty braces to indicate an empty code block. Or better yet, just use the reverse of the condition and don't include an `else`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Check for each button if it is enabled. Roll die if so (implicit: otherwise don't). 
    if (Dicebtn1.IsEnabled) rndNum1 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 7); // max is exclusive !
    if (Dicebtn2.IsEnabled) rndNum2 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 7);
    if (Dicebtn3.IsEnabled) rndNum3 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 7);
    if (Dicebtn4.IsEnabled) rndNum4 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 7);
    if (Dicebtn5.IsEnabled) rndNum5 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 7);
    if (Dicebtn6.IsEnabled) rndNum6 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 7);
}
```

Mind that you do not need to have an `else` with every `if`. Just drop it.

The maxValue in [Next(int,int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is **ex**clusive, so if you want [1..6] you need to call `Next(1,7)`.

---

One more thing:

Regarding your original code:

```
if (Dicebtn1_Click) rndNum1 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    else 
    rndNum2 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    rndNum3 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    rndNum4 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    rndNum5 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    rndNum6 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
```

Mind that this would be equivalent to:

```
if (Dicebtn1_Click)
{
   rndNum1 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
}
else
{ 
    rndNum2 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
} // <= Yes , HERE!
// Rest will be executed unconditionally!
    rndNum3 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    rndNum4 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    rndNum5 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
    rndNum6 = rndNumbers.Next(1, 6);
```

I found it good practice for myself to *always* use parenthesis. (With very very small number of exceptions ... ) At least as long as the code is "under construction".

---

And finally (thanks to @RufusL's comment on the question) :

*"Is there a way to tell an if statement if a condition is true do nothing"*

```
if(condition){}else{ doSomething(); }
```

or

```
if(!condition){ doSomething();}
```

or

```
if(condition == false){ doSomething();}
```

or if you want to be explicitly verbose about your decision:

```
if(condition){ /* DO NOTHING */ } else {doSomething();}
```

...